# Google Sheet Show Image

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm currently having trouble displaying an image in Google Sheet. I have a Google Form template in which I'm using the FILE UPLOAD function, and I believe the image will be saved in Google Drive, correct?

The responses on the Google Form will be connected on a Google Sheet. So, using Google Sheets, I created a template in which I use the VLOOKUP function to display specific data. When I use the VLOOKUP for the image, it only displays the URL path. Is it possible for me to show it as the image itself?

Upon researching, it says that I need to use `=IMAGE()` to show an image. However, it seems that it is not working with the `=VLOOKUP` function.

This is the formula that I used `=IMAGE((VLOOKUP(F2,AppData,2,0)))` and it only gave me a blank cell.

[SAMPLE SPREADSHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rBE_tT_1dlu3cArDPEV-no61Un114mNyQlZphLtTzUY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: In order to show the image using `=IMAGE()`, the URL of the image is required to be a publicly shared link. But, I think that the file uploaded with Google Form is not publicly shared. So, unfortunately, the file cannot be directly used with `=IMAGE()`. But, fortunately, recently, Class CellImage and Class CellImageBuilder have been added. By this, in the current stage, when the image file is uploaded by submitting the form, I think that the image can be shown in a cell using Google Apps Script. How about this? If this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike I already enabled the link publicly but still not working. Maybe your idea using Google Apps Script can work.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `I already enabled the link publicly but still not working.`, in that case, I'm worried that the URL might be required to be modified. Although I'm not sure about your actual situation from your question, for example, how about `=IMAGE("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=###fileID###&export=download")`?

Comment: @Tanaike the link is not like that. `https://drive.google.com/open?id=######` it look like this.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When you modify your current URL to my proposes one, what result will you obtain?

Comment: @Tanaike it shows the image.

Comment: @Tanaike I changed the `open` to `uc` and add the `&export=download`. How can I use it as formula?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. When I tested `=IMAGE("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=###fileID###&export=download")` using the publicly shared image file, the image could be put. So, unfortunately, I cannot replicate `the result is a blank cell`. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly understand your current situation, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you cannot show the image using the same URL with me, for example, in that case, how about using Google Apps Script?

Comment: @Tanaike I edit my reply. It works now but I don't have an idea on how can I create a formula where in the `open` will be `uc` and add the `&export=download`.

Comment: @Tanaike I can accept answers using Google Apps Script if it will be easier.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood that in your situation, the webContentLink (`https://drive.google.com/uc?id=###fileID###&export=download`) could be used. About `but I don't have an idea on how can I create a formula where in the open will be uc and add the &export=download. `, in this case, it is required to see your sample Spreadsheet and your sample URL. Can you provide these information?

Comment: @Tanaike please see the sample spreadsheet above.

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing a sample Spreadsheet. From your sample Spreadsheet, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `VLOOKUP(F2,AppData,2,0)` is the URL like `https://drive.google.com/open?id=######`, in your situation, how about using the following sample formula?

#### Sample formula:

```
=IMAGE("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id="&INDEX(SPLIT(VLOOKUP(F2,AppData,2,0),"="),1,2))
```

or

```
=IMAGE("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id="&REGEXEXTRACT(VLOOKUP(F2,AppData,2,0),"id\=(.+)"))
```

- By this, the file ID is retrieved from your URL of `https://drive.google.com/open?id=###`, and the webContentLink is created.

#### Result:

When your sample Spreadsheet is used, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- This sample supposes that your URL is like `https://drive.google.com/open?id=###`. If the URL is different, this sample might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.
- This sample also supposes that your image file is publicly sharead. Please be careful this.

Comment: It worked! Thank you!

Comment: @cjwrk Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved.