# google drive link from a google form upload embeded into the spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

Hi I have a google form setup to allow the user to upload images using the form
However I get the links to the drive folder instead of the actual image

I thought going from

https://drive.google.com/open?id=imageid  to  https://drive.google.com/uc?id=imageid

would solve the problem, however it does not.

I want the actual image to be embeded into the cell in the google sheet. not a google drive link to the image on a seperate page. I would like for this to be the case as I want to then add the actuall image in the description field in Trello

https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=imageid
Allows me to downloade the file.

when I try

=IMAGE("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=imageid")
I get a blank cell.

Any advice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Sheet Show Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70857765/google-sheet-show-image)

Comment: Related question: [How display images from Google Drive on Gsheet cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60290489/1330560)